# ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.WRITE_LOG' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I get an error from a trigger called WRITE_LOG which I didn't create. I try to run my update code which is supposed to trigger a trigger called save_log. My main table is:

```
Create table USERS(
  NameSurname varchar2(20),
  DateOfBirth varchar2(13),
  Gender varchar2(1),
  IdentityNumber varchar2(11),
  Username varchar2(10),
  Password varchar2(12),
  AllergyInformation varchar2(100),
  ChronicDiseaseInformation varchar2(100),
  VaccineDose varchar2(10),
  ChoosenVaccine varchar2(100),
  ChoosenHospital varchar2(50),
  ChoosenDoctor varchar2(20),
  PregnantInformation varchar2(1),
  AttendSessions varchar2(50),
  Primary key(Username, IdentityNumber)
)
```

My table which saves the values before the update is this table:

```
CREATE TABLE save_log(
  uname varchar2(10),
  vdose varchar2(10),
  cvaccine varchar2(100),
  chospital varchar2(50),
  cdoctor varchar2(20),
  log_date DATE,
)
```

Lastly, my trigger is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_save
BEFORE UPDATE
ON HR_E.Users
For Each Row
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO save_log(uname , vdose, cvaccine, chospital, cdoctor, log_date) 
    VALUES( :new.Username, :new.VaccineDose, :new.ChoosenVaccine, :new.ChoosenHospital, :new.ChoosenDoctor, SYSDATE); 
END;
```

I use Oracle 11.2 application express for this code. I created my trigger and tables without a problem and I really don't understand what causes this 'SYSTEM.WRITE_LOG' to trigger. I tried to change the table's name and didn't work. I saw that `select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'TRIGGERNAME'` might give me an answer but it didn't find anything wrong in my trigger. I am afraid to drop the 'SYSTEM.WRITE_LOG' thinking that it might be important to the oracle but I don't know what to do anymore. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

The problem is solved after I dropped `USERS` table and recreated it. I don't know what really was the reason for the trigger error but I just want to share it. I hope it will help the people which might have the same problem as me. I want to thank everyone who tried to help me :)

Comment: Can you check what SYSTEM.WRITE_LOG trigger does? If not (as you don't have access to it), ask your DBA.

Comment: Never modify anything in SYS or SYSTEM schemas.  You are asking for trouble.What schema are you creating these tables under?

Comment: @Littlefoot I dont know how to check what SYSTEM.WRITE_LOG do since I am still new to the sql. I tried to use select but it says its empty. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you do `SELECT text FROM all_source WHERE name = 'WRITE_LOG' AND type = 'TRIGGER' AND owner = 'SYSTEM';` or alternatively, `SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER','WRITE_LOG', 'SYSTEM') FROM DUAL` (something like this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=086eee116d6671a4e2c45e735626fd36)).

Comment: @MT0 HR_E is my schema name and where all my tables and triggers are. That's why I am confused. I never try to do anything with SYSTEM triggers yet here it is.

Comment: @MT0 It says no data found for the first one and for the second one it says "ORA-31603: object "WRITE_LOG" of type TRIGGER not found in schema "SYSTEM" "

Comment: Does it return rows when you do `SELECT text FROM all_source WHERE name = 'LOG_SAVE' AND type = 'TRIGGER' AND owner = 'HR_E';`?

Comment: @MT0 yes it does.

Comment: Drop your trigger and try to insert manually into the `USERS` table and see if it raises an exception. If that works, then try to manually insert into the `SAVE_LOG` table to match the data you just created in `USERS` and see if that raises an exception ... finally, if they both work then recreate the trigger and try inserting data again. If that fails then try using different names for the trigger or the tables .... (you have a weird error and we don't know what to do so just debug it in tiny steps making sure each bit works and looking for ways to change whatever weird thing is erroring).

Comment: If you come to the end of debugging it and it still doesn't work then talk to your DBA and get them to help or contact MyOracle support.

Comment: @MT0 after dropping the trigger, updating USERS manually gives the same error. I created a different table that has the same values, insert the same data then update it and strangely it didn't give any exceptions. The only difference they have is I declared USERS value at java (eclipse)  and new table's values at oracle. Is there a difference between the two of them maybe which I might not know. SAVE_LOG didn't give any exception.

Comment: I doubt it but there is always there is a possibility that a difference is being introduced by different methods Java connects to the database compared to using SQL/Plus or SQL Developer. However, if it is working when you call the table something like `USER_DETAILS` and is not working when you call the table `USERS` then go for the quick win and rename the table .... unless you have a hard requirement to call it `USERS` in which case you're going to have to debug the issue and find where that trigger is getting called from (good luck if you do).

Comment: Just a couple of side observations that having nothing to do with your reported problem.  First, "Users" is a poor name for a table. It's too much like the reserved word USER and can easily lead to problems resulting from a simple typo.  Second, and more importantly, your 'DateOfBirth' should be defined as a DATE, not a VARCHAR2.